# XHTML, XML или html?

Tags: html

С html разобрался, но прочитал статью про XML и XHTML, пишут что это более лучший язык для сайтов и что он заменит html! Я что не тот язык выучил?

Comment: То, что вы читали, устарело примерно 15 лет назад.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> С html разобрался

Это хорошо. Теперь разберитесь с CSS. И тогда вы сможете создать свою первую страничку.

> прочитал статью про XML и XHTML

Это ещё лучше. Как однажды сказал русский полководец Александр Васильевич Суворов: *"Ученье — свет, а неученье — тьма"*.

> про XML и XHTML, пишут что это более лучший язык для сайтов

Неправду пишут (хотя, есть моменты, где можно и поспорить). Но не лучшие точно, а скорее немного разные языки.

> и что он заменит html

По крайней мере в ближайшее время точно не заменит. А что будет дальше, то поживём - увидим. Возможно, что в будущем не будет ни того, ни другого, и ничего из перечисленного, а что-то совершенно новое. Время покажет.

> Я что не тот язык выучил?

А это зависит от того, что вы планируете создавать и для какой цели изучаете тот или иной язык. Главное, и в первую очередь, это знать русский язык, потому как он один из самых сложных языков во всём мире.

**Желаю удачи в "грызении" гранита науки!**

---

ps

> *То, что вы читали, устарело примерно 15 лет назад. – andreymal*

*Ну не сказать. Смотря что читали и о чем. Например, с XML я работал как 15 лет назад, так и сегодня работаю.*